# Steering wheel pedals broken behavior

Tags: windows, windows-10, joystick

UPDATE: THE STUFF JUST RANDOMLY STARTED WORKING! NO IDEA WHY SO DON'T ASK ME.

UPDATE #2: IT BROKE AGAIN!

My Tracer Sierra Steering wheel has been acting weird after installing Windows 1909 KB4592449, KB4598229, KB4586878 and KB4535680. Normally most games detected the steering wheel turning as left stick x-axis and the pedals as left stick y-axis. Now everything works the same, except the pedals are broken. The pedals still work fine on my Chromebook so the problem is with my PC/Windows OS.

The problem is:

My PC and games detect my throttle pedal always pressed about 90%. When I actually press the throttle pedal, it goes up to 100%. Pressing the brake pedal doesn't do anything. The steering wheel and pedals worked earlier without additional drivers.

UPDATE: Some things have changed and made the stuff even more complicated, so F, I'm gonna post a video! The gamepad tester used in the video can be found at https://gamepad-tester.com/. Video coming soon!

Here's everything I've tried so far (none have worked):

1. I tried using the steering wheel in safe mode, no change.
2. I made sure all drivers are up to date, they already were.
3. I tried the driver included with my steering wheel, no change at all, probably because it's meant for Windows <7.
4. I tried reinstalling every single USB driver, no change.
5. I tried to calibrate the controller in Windows game controller calibration, this made the pedals' default position drop to the normal 0%, but the throttle pedal is way too sensitive and brake pedal still does nothing.
6. I tried to use the steering wheel from any other USB port, no change.

My Windows version is 64bit 1909.

Steering wheel model is

TRAJOY34008

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a non-reproducible problem that just randomly started working by itself.